# XPath performance (XPath vs sax)

Tags: dom, xpath, sax

I have a 2 GB XML data which needs to be parsed to fetch some value and i also have the paths which needs to be fetched. Do you think XPath will me memory intensive ?

Comment: Yes, probably. What are the paths?

Comment: you should use a `SAX` approach and avoid `XPATH`/`DOM parser` since they manipulate the whole XML DOM tree and will therefore consume a lot of memory.

Comment: /customers/customer/City .. this is a very general one i m testing. Using sax i will have to maintain the xml structure , i was thinking there is some easy way out. But now looks like i need to use sax.